# Calling multiple methods on an event handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to do this

```
@click="update_value && selected = true"
```

Clearly it fails and so does this:

```
@click="update_value"
@click="selected = true">
```

How do I run multiple methods from a single event handler without creating a parent function?

Answer (score 2):

Well after 30 minutes:

```
@click="update_value; selected = true"
```

However this doesn't work if you try to call multiple **methods**

```
@click="update_value; submit_form"
```

Comment: If it is resolved, you can mark it so by selecting the tick mark. This ensures that it will not show up in list of "unanswered" questions :)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that restriction in StackOverflow. Thanks for this info! I generally visit once in a while to look out for unanswered questions, and see if I can help with any of them. Lately, there are a lot of unanswered questions, but most of them are actually resolved :)

Comment: @Mani the answer is actually no good. It doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: `@click` takes the function reference and calls it for you. Alternatively, if you want to execute multi-line javascript, you need to invoke the function directly like `@click="update_value(); submit_form()"` - can you check if this works?